# Is mass really lost in favor of energy after fission?

Tags: energy, nuclear-physics, mass-energy, radioactivity, binding-energy

If in nuclear fission, the sum of the masses of the resulting atoms is the same as the parent ($\text{U}_{236}$, after fission is $\text{Cs}_{93}$ + $\text{Rb}_{140}$ + *2 neutrons*), where does the concept that mass is lost in favor of energy come from? Keeping in mind the formula:
$$E=mc^2$$
Are some electrons and protons of the progenitor disappearing in favor of energy?

Comment: The nuclear reaction that you have written is incorrect. The product should have 3 neutrons.

Comment: From my knowledge, I believe that one of the neutrons is the one who caused the reaction, correct me if I am wrong. In that case, I may need to reformulate the question.

Comment: The one neutron reacts with the $U_{235}$ nucleus to produce $U_{236}$, which undergoes nuclear fission to produce the products.

Comment: Totally fine, then my reasoning was kind of wrong (I have edited the question). Anyways, in that case, what is the portion of mass that is really transformed into energy?

Comment: Try this
https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/667132/313823
This confusion seems to come up a lot.

Answer (score 5):

The total number of [nucleons](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleon) (protons and neutrons) is the same after nuclear fission as it was before. The energy released in fission comes from the difference in [binding energy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binding_energy) between the fissile material and its fission products.

Answer (score 3):

The atomic *number* is not the same as the atomic *mass*. The *number* is just the sum of the counts of protons and neutrons in a nucleus. That number is conserved during fission (be sure to include the escaping neutrons). The mass is an actual measurement and accounts for the masses of the protons and neutrons *and* the energy content of the nucleus. Therefore your assertion that the masses before and after fission are the same is wrong.